# Add value into database plus 1

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

In my database I have:

Row ID - Driver ID - Log ID.

Row ID is unique and auto-increments. What I want is for the Log ID to be unique for each row that has that Driver ID.

For example say a row is inserted with Driver ID 1 I want that row to have a Log ID of 1 but the next time a row is inserted with Driver ID 1 I want it to have a Log ID of 2.

How can I achieve this?

By way for database i am using PHPMyAdmin.

----------------Edit----------------------

This is what i have in my PHP now, but it says:

On the webpage: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'FinesCost' at row 1

And i dump the variables and get this: string(2) "16" string(2) "16" string(2) "16" so i dont understand why it is saying incorrect integer value and why it is saying they are undefines because they are very clearly defined.

In the PHP error log: [19-Jul-2013 10:44:18 Europe/Minsk] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: FinesCostP‌ost2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hosting\Dan\JWT\drivers-log-send.php on line 336
[19-Jul-2013 10:44:18 Europe/Minsk] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: TravelExpensesPo‌​st2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hosting\Dan\JWT\drivers-log-send.php on line 336

///PHP TO INSERT DRIVER'S BANK DETAILS INTO BANK DATABASE

```
session_start(); 

$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name="jwtdriversbank"; // Table name

$un = "";
$usrname = "";
$usrpass = "";
$userID = "";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset ($_SESSION['usrName']))
{
    $usrname = $_SESSION['usrName'];
}
else
{
    echo "4";
}

//var_dump ($usrname);

if(isset ($_SESSION['usrPass']))
{
    $usrpass = $_SESSION['usrPass'];
}
else
{
    echo "5";
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM jwtdrivers WHERE username='$usrname' and password='$usrpass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$userID = $rows['id'];

//var_dump ($userID);

if($userID == "")
{
    echo "3";
}
else
{

            $TotalProfitPost = $TotalProfit;
    $LateFeePost = $LateFee;
    $FinesCostPost2 = $FinesCost;
    $TravelExpensesPost2 = $TravelExpenses;
    $FuelCostPost = $FuelCost;
    $CargoDamagePost = $CargoDamage;
    $TruckDamagePost = $TruckDamage;

    var_dump ($TotalProfitPost);
    var_dump($FinesCostPost2);
    var_dump($TravelExpensesPost2);

    $sql="INSERT INTO jwtdriversbank2 (DriverID, LogID, TotalProfit, LateFee, FinesCost, TravelExpenses, FuelCost, CargoDamage, TruckDamage) VALUES ('$userID', COALESCE((Select MAX(LogID) from jwtdriversbank2 tab2 where tab2.DriverID = '$userID'),0)+1,'$TotalProfitPost','$LateFeePost', '$FinesCostP‌ost2' , '$TravelExpensesPo‌​st2' ,'$FuelCostPost','$CargoDamagePost','$TruckDamagePost')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

}
```

Comment: In your example can I have an other row with DriverID 2 and logID1?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes @DavidLevel that is what i want to be able to happen.

Comment: @Danbyization try my answer it should works for this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a primary key for the two columns.

It should do the trick.

Look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) for help

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_DriverID PRIMARY KEY (DriverID,LogID)
```

Do not forget to drop the first primary key because you will not need it no more.

EDIT : COMPLETE WITH THE OTHER ANSWER

Here is the code to insert your data.

```
Insert into <table_name>
values p_RowID, p_DriverID, COALESCE((Select MAX(Log_id) from <table_name> tab2 where tab2.Driver_id = p_DriverID),0)+1;
```

That should close the question.

You did not defined variable because PHP can't read them.
I opened your program inside VIM editor and I found "<200c>" char inside $FineCostPost2 in the SQL query. You have to change it to make it work.

Comment: But i dont want the driverID to be unique and i dont want the logid to be unique either

Comment: It won't but the couple will be unique. That means you can't have twice DriverId2 and logID2. The primary key constraint will only use the couple not each column. You got what I mean?

Comment: I tried but i got an error "there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: Don't use auto-increment for it, just PRIMARY KEY

Comment: That's eactly what i did i clicked the primary key button in php my admin

Comment: Please do not use PHPMyAdmin like this, try to do it using query because I don't think PHPMyAdmin is able to do it. Have a look at the answer I gave you all you need

Comment: Oh ok and how do i do it as a query?

Comment: I ran the code you posted and it came up with this " #1068 - Multiple primary key defined"

Comment: Oh ok Is this correct then cus i run this and i get an error saying it is incorrect. ALTER TABLE jwtdriversbank
DROP PRIMARY KEY
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_DriverID PRIMARY KEY (DriverID,LogID)

Comment: Nope, DROP PRIMARY KEY first then do the command. Create a copy of the table and try to test. You will learn a lot like this.

Comment: I did drop primary key first like this "ALTER TABLE jwtdriversbank DROP PRIMARY KEY" but it gives me this "#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Comment: This answer will make sure you dont have a duplicate pair (Driver ID and Log ID) but it wouldnt answer your question on how to get the next log id value.

Comment: @JafarKofahi exactly, maybe we should try to merge our two answers :)

Comment: @DavidLevel You can combine them if you want just get this thing working please lol

Comment: @JafarKofahi I did the merge thanks for your code. I add to put this comment because it's your answer too :)

Comment: @DavidLevel Ive already got that code in my PHP but its not working its giving me errors see my original post

Comment: I'll debug it for you but this is not the first purpose of the question. Maybe you should make it resolved an create a new one...

Comment: @DavidLevel I thought about that but i then thought well i have the code but i havent actually verified whether it works or not because it hasnt actually inserted any log id's in. Bu thank you i will appreciate it if you can debug it.

Comment: You should not put simple quotes while data is an integer first. I'm trying to find why is the variable not defined

Comment: @DavidLevel What do you mean? And yeah thats what ive been trying to work out cus as far as i'm aware i've defined it perfectly.

Comment: Inside your query I saw some stuff like '$var', MySQL will interpret it as a String and not as an integer

Comment: No you did not defined it. I'm looking in my IDE and it seems that they look like the same but not exactly. Which IDE do you use. Maybe a char was hide by it

Comment: So when inserting the values i need to do it like - $DriverID,$TruckDamage etc. And i use Notepad++. How is not defined i dont understand that.

Comment: It is not defined because you work on Windows system to program and your server is a Linux one I think some chars are different between the two OS and sometimes they are hide I'll try to see in VIM.

Comment: For the integer answer, not always, adapt when it is a string or an integer. Did you try before posting?

Comment: The server is not linux it is deffinitely windows cus it is my mates server and it runs on windows server 2012 so deffinitely windows and oh so just trial and error then.

Comment: I just wrote at the end of the answer what's happening

Comment: Have you just try to copy the one who is working and paste it over the one not working?

Comment: @DavidLevel Oh ok but how do i get rid of this <200c> if i cant see it in notepad++????

Comment: Look at the comment please

Comment: Yeah you wrote "That should close the question.

You did not defined variable because PHP can't read them. I opened your program inside VIM editor and I found "<200c>" char inside $FineCostPost2 in the SQL query. You have to change it to make it work." That doesnt tell me how to fix the problem though.

Comment: Have you just try to copy the one who is working and paste it over the one not working?

Comment: No i haven't look this is what i have ATM "$sql="INSERT INTO jwtdriversbank2 (DriverID, LogID, TotalProfit, LateFee, FinesCost, TravelExpenses, FuelCost, CargoDamage, TruckDamage) VALUES ($userID, COALESCE((Select MAX(LogID) from jwtdriversbank2 tab2 where tab2.DriverID = '$userID'),0)+1,$TotalProfitPost,$LateFeePost, $FinesCostP‌ost2 , $TravelExpensesPo‌​st2 ,$FuelCostPost,$CargoDamagePost,$TruckDamagePost)";" What do i need to change??

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO jwtdriversbank2 (DriverID, LogID, TotalProfit, LateFee, FinesCost, TravelExpenses, FuelCost, CargoDamage, TruckDamage) VALUES ('$userID', COALESCE((Select MAX(LogID) from jwtdriversbank2 tab2 where tab2.DriverID = '$userID'),0)+1,'$TotalProfitPost','$LateFeePost', '$FinesCostPost2' , '$TravelExpensesPost2' ,'$FuelCostPost','$CargoDamagePost','$TruckDamagePost')";

Comment: Use this, I removed the special chars

Comment: Yes!! Thank you it works but i don't understand how cus it looks eactly the same as mine. But thank you very much. How can i avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: Use a more simple IDE like eclipse, sublime Text 2 or an other. I don't use to program with notepad so I can't help you with this. Can you make the answer resolved please?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution would be to use a subquery to find the maximum log (last log id) then increment it, something like this

```
Insert into <table_name>
values p_RowID, p_DriverID, COALESCE((Select MAX(Log_id) from <table_name> tab2 where tab2.Driver_id = p_DriverID),0)+1;
```

Here `p_RowID` and `p_DriverID` are the values you pass to insert into your table. The `Coalesce` function would check the given value and if it is `NULL` then it would replace it with the second parameter, in this case `0`

Comment: Not using Oracle uing PHPMyAdmin

Comment: So you cant write an SQL query?

Comment: Well yeah i can but because you mentioned oracle i am assuming that the code you posted is for oracle and so will not work with PHP My Admin.

Comment: @Danbyization I just found out that PHP My Admin is actually MySQL, try my query and I think it would work fine since MySql does have a `COALESCE` function, the other syntax is just **SQL**

Comment: @JafarKofahi I just looked about COALESCE and it works with MySQL too you right. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html?iframe=true&width=100%&he

Comment: Ok right this is what i have ATM "$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (DriverID, TotalProfit, LateFee, FinesCost, TravelExpenses, FuelCost, CargoDamage, TruckDamage, COALESCE((Select MAX(LogID) from jwtdriversbank tab2 where tab2.DriverID = p.DriverID),0)+1)VALUES('$userID','$TotalProfitPost','$LateFeePost','$FinesCostPost','$TravelExpensesPost','$FuelCostPost','$CargoDamagePost'," and it gives me an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax".

Comment: @Danbyization I noticed a couple of things in your query, first you need to have a space between `VALUES` and the parantheses. Second the subquery would give you a value **IT IS NOT** a column field, third you have **9 fields** (one is wrong) in your `INTO` clause while your `VALUES` clause have **7**

Comment: I dont have MySQL right now but I tried to fix as many errors as possible:
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (DriverID, TotalProfit, LateFee, FinesCost, TravelExpenses, FuelCost, CargoDamage, TruckDamage,**??logID??**)
VALUES '$userID','$TotalProfitPost','$LateFeePost','$FinesCostP‌ost','$TravelExpensesPost','$FuelCostPost','$CargoDamagePost',**'$TruckDamage' whats the value for this**, COALESCE((Select MAX(**LogID**) from jwtdriversbank tab2 where tab2.DriverID = '$userID'),0)+1

Check the column names for the bolded fields

Comment: @Danbyization Your error message is telling you that you are trying to insert an empty string value into an integer field. I would suggest that before you do the insert check the fields and if they are empty then assign them a `null` or `0` value.